# Specific layout with ViewFlipper

Tags: java, android, layout

I'm beginning Android development and I'm dealing with layout, ViewFlipper and aligmnent of elements... I tried to accomplish layout below with LinearLayout and TableLayout in it, but alignment of Boxes was a mess.

```
    ------------------------------------------------------------
    |                          Title                           |
    |                                                          |
    |-----------------------ViewFlipper------------------------|
    |         |                    |                 |         |
    |         |      Box    1      |      Box  2     |         |
    |         |                    |                 |         |
    |    <    |--------------------------------------|    >    |
    |         |                    |                 |         |
    |         |      Box    3      |      Box  4     |         |
    |         |                    |                 |         |
    ------------------------------------------------------------
```

For any help I'll be grateful :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with RelativeLayouts, it should be simpler

[Relative Layout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.html)